# Using set theory to count the possible paths on an XY plane

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm taking an introductory discrete math course, and we're studying set theory. It's going okay, but I read an example problem which gave me some difficulty. I've included a screenshot of the problem. My difficulty is that doesn't it appear the upward moves occur at 3,5,7 not 2,5,8 like the book says. Also, isn't the set we're dealing with {1,2,...,7} not {1,2,...,8}? .[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the numbered grid, that will just confuse you. Instead, count from the start of the path. The first line segment is horizontal but the second line segment is vertical so we include $2$ in the set. The third and fourth are horizontal, but the fifth is vertical so we include $5$ in the set, and so on.

There are a total of $8$ line segments needed to make a path between the two points and so the elements in the associated set of a path are the integers between $1$ and $8$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget zero there at start.

Comment: So instead of counting {0,1,2,...7} the book is going the way of {1,2,...,8}?

Comment: exactly . Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

The coordinate of the starting point is $(2,1)$ and that of the ending point is $(7,4)$. So we have $7-2+4-1=8$ "moves".